# Plivo - 404 error, call not found, when I try to record inbound call

Tags: php, laravel, plivo

I am trying to record the inbound call but so far I am only getting the **404 call not found error** when record is activated.

This is my code so far (I am using Laravel and latest Plivo SDK):

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->authId       = config('AUTH_ID');
        $this->authToken    = config('AUTH_TOKEN');
        $this->sourceNumber = config('sms.SMS_SOURCE_NUMBER');
        $this->_answerURL   = config('voiceCall.CALL_ANSWER_URL');
        $this->_recordURL   = config('voiceCall.INBOUND_RECORD_URL');
        $this->_hangupURL   = config('voiceCall.HANGUP_URL');

        $this->_plivo    = new RestClient($this->authId, $this->authToken);

        $this->_response = new Response();

        $this->_mp3Url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/plivocloud/Trumpet.mp3';

        $this->_request = $request;

    }
```

The answer method:

```
public function answer()
    {
        $response = $this->_response;

        $response->addPlay($this->_mp3Url);

        $response->addRecord([
                'action'            => $this->_recordURL,
                'startOnDialAnswer' => "true",
                'redirect'          => "false",
                'maxLength'        => 600
            ]);

        Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/debug.log');

        Log::info([
            'Record'   => 'This is from inbound answer',
            'Response' => $response
        ]);

        return response($response->toXML(), 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    }
```

The record method:

```
public function record()
    {
        Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/debug.log');


        $uuid = $this->_request->input('CallUUID');

        Log::info(['This is Call UUID' => $uuid]);

        $response = $this->_plivo->calls->startRecording($uuid);

        Log::info([
            'Record'   => 'This is from record inbound record',
            'Response' => $response,
            'CallUUID' => $this->_request->input('CallUUID'),
            'Request'  => $this->_request->all(),
        ]);
    }
```

The **request** is giving back the proper **call uuid**, and

```
$response = $this->_plivo->calls->startRecording($uuid);
```

is the code which is used in the docs. Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

Is this an incoming call to your Plivo number? I see that you're returning an XML that contains a Play and Record element. This Record XML will take care of recording the call after the Play ends.

Are you making a Record API request to record this again? Which Call UUID are you passing to this API request?

For an inbound call, the Call UUID is sent to the answer URL. Are you using this Call UUID?